# JSP search form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, search, get

I'm trying to implement a Search method into a JSP through a form, but I'm stuck on sending the text from the form further to the submit action.I made something like this until now:

```
 <form onsubmit="location.href='news.do?action=Search&search_string=${search}'" >
 Search: <input type="text" name="search">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit your form as a GET instead of POST, how about this?

```
<form method = get action="news.do" >
<input type="hidden" name="action" value = "Search">
Search: <input type="text" name="search_string">
</form>
```

This will send a request to news.do?action=Search&search_string=fsdfdsf

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
String query = (request.getParameter("query")!=null && request.getParameter("query").trim().length()>0)?request.getParameter("query").trim():"";
if(action!=null && action.trim.equalsIgnoreCase("search"))
{
//do the search
}
%>
<form action="<%=application.getContextPath() + "/my.jsp"%>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
                <input type="text" class="text" value="<%=(request.getParameter("query")!=null && request.getParameter("query").trim().length()>0)?request.getParameter("query").trim():"Search"%>" name="query" />
</form>
```